# PHP query using an association from another query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to INSERT into my SQL table in PHP using an association I already returned from a previous SELECT query. But the compiler is giving me a syntax error 'unexpected $EOF'.

Essentially, this is what I am doing:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$user.username'";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($db, $query2);
    $new_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

    $query3 = "INSERT INTO new_table (new_user_id) VALUES('$new_user['user_id']');";
    mysqli_query($db, $query3);
```

Query 3 is the one giving me the error. I have referenced variables like this before with the fetch association. I'm incredibly new to PHP, but isn't that fetch by association just creating a dictionary? Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the output of $new_user['user_id']?

Comment: @SteveMulvihill $new_user['user_id'] returns my correct ID. I don't get errors if I do $new_user.user_id. Is that a way to reference it?

Comment: @user3783243 what do you mean?

Comment: This would not cause the unexpected EOF but you have some issues here. `$user.username` -- is that supposed to be an object property? PHP does not understand that syntax.  `$user->username` or if an array `$user['username']` but dot notation is not part of PHP.  Later you must encluse `$new_user['user_id']` in `{} `as `{$new_user['user_id']}` to use it in a single quoted string while also quoting the array key. See examples of PHP string double quoting https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I appreciate that, I will give it a read.

Comment: @user3783243 Yeah, I have two tables that I keep querying. Basically I create a user via a username, then query a second time to grab the user id which is auto populated. I use the user id to start my second table entries. Then have to use another query to grab the unique id after the second table entry is completed. Is there an easier way to do this? Should I be googling paramterized queries?

Comment: If one query is dependent on the result of a previous query then you might want to consider the use of transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is with the single quote marks in the code below:

```
VALUES('$new_user['user_id']')
```

If you were to set a variable outside of the query like this it should work:

```
$user_id = $new_user['user_id'];
$query3 = "INSERT INTO new_table (new_user_id) VALUES('$user_id');";
```

I would also suggest you parameterize your queries.

Comment: But I could also do {$new_user['user_id']} as well?

Answer (score 1):

The `EOF` error is short for `end of file` which means the PHP doesn't think your script ends where you think it does. This is usually caused by a control block not being closed e.g. `{...code ?>` with no closing `}`.

You have some other issues that should be address. You shouldn't use variables in queries. You can't use a quoted index in a string. You don't need to execute 2 queries to do what you are trying to do.

```
INSERT INTO new_table (new_user_id) SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name= ?
```

Should be work. Use that with `prepare`, `bind_param`, and `execute` and your code will be much more secure.

1. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
3. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

You also can read more about these concepts here, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

Also if interested in how that SQL query works see this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html.